# How to read schema model from an existing Postgres db in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I've been looking at many tutorials on building graphQl servers on Node.js.
Most people are defining a schema on the `schema.js` file and then
running it to build a DB from the defined model.

I am wondering how one would go about loading a model from an existing Postgres database.

Example:
Say we have the following Postgres tables

`users` with columns [id, user_name, email, town_code]

`town` with columns [town_code, town_name, library]

The two tables already have a relationship and have existing data.
How can I get this model and import it into my `schema.js` for my Node server

Comment: Which ORM are you using?

Comment: I am using sequelize